# Open Iconic fonts not showing up on Windows 7 Chrome

Tags: icons, glyphicons, iconic

I'm using open iconic with bootstrap, it's working fine on Ubuntu/OS X but when I try to access it on Windows 7 via Chrome I get blank squares instead of icons. Then I checked the downloaded file via network tab, instead of the icons, the file shows the regular "abcd...". Why does it happens?

Comment: did you find the solution